# Bash как записать %{time_total} из Curl в файл?

Tags: bash, curl, shell

Необходимо провести тестирование странички на скорость отклика при посещении указанного числа пользователей. Для этого я воспользовался Bash командой curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" -s -w 'time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o result.txt https://site.ua/userapi/installationList
```

Теперь мне необходимо записать значение этого %{time_total} в файл например time.txt с нумерацией строчек.

Также подскажите, как этот скрипт можно будет запустить 10 раз, чтобы он выполнился не последовательно, а параллельно?

**Updated**

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0;
for i in {1..51};
do curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" -s -w 'time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o /home/it/Documents/overload-folder/result.txt https://site.com/userapi/installationList & i=$(($i+1));
done
```

**Updated 2**

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0;
for i in {1..11};
do curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" -s -w $i: 'time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o /home/it/Documents/overload-folder/result.txt https://site.com/userapi/installationList & i=$(($i+1));
done
```

Comment: На вторую часть вопроса ответ "запускайте через &": curl -H "Authoriza..." & curl -H "Authoriza..." & curl -H "Authoriza..." & curl -H "Authoriza..." ...

Comment: а если как цикл, например если мне надо 50 раз запустить эту строчку, 50 раз копировать - это не красиво, хотя начну с малого, и за это спасибо.

Comment: `i=0; while [[ $i -lt 50 ]]; do curl... & i=$(($i+1)); done` или `for i in {1..50}; do curl... & done`

Comment: для нумерации можно тот же $i использовать из цикла: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MyToken" -s -w $i:' time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o result.txt https://site.ua/userapi/installationList`

Comment: Цикл получился, спасибо, но к сожалению если я добавляю $i: то выводится не время а содержимое параметров URL

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос как вы реализовали скрипт, что бы наглядно было видно в чем проблема

Comment: Добавил полный код, но без $i:

Comment: `$i:'time:\t%{time_total}\n'` уберите пробел между символами, либо укажите так `"$i: time:\t%{time_total}\n"`

Comment: Да, спасибо, "$i: 'time:\t%{time_total}\n" - сработало. Как можно вам лайк за это поставить? что-то не нашел ) Спасибо большое!

Comment: Подскажите, а как корректно завершить этот скрипт? Я написал `exit` в конце файла, но после выполнения всё-равно приходится нажимать в терминале ctrl+c ?